# why does `^[^[:digit:]]` match a digit and a new line character before the digit

Tags: regex, emacs

In Emacs's regex, why does `^[^[:digit:]]` match a digit and a new line character before the digit, e.g. it will matches the whole of the second and the third line of

```
1

1
```

but not the first line.

My original thought is to use `^[^[:digit:]]` to match a line not starting with a digit. Why does that not work for my purpose? What regex can work for my purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: Weird; it works with grep.

Answer (score 1):

According to the **[documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/emacs-regular-expression-syntax.html)** it seems that you cannot use`[:digit:]` in a character class:

> Bracket expressions are used to match ranges of characters. Bracket expressions where the range is backward, for example ‘[z-a]’, are ignored. Within square brackets, ‘\’ is taken literally. Character classes are not supported, so for example you would need to use ‘[0-9]’ instead of ‘[[:digit:]]’.

This explains why you cannot use your regex, since you are trying to negate `[:digit:]` in a character class.

I don't know why that doesn't work but you can achieve the same by doing:

```
^[^0-9]
```

Comment: The documentation you referred to is outdated, modern Emacs versions support character classes like `[:digit:]`.

Comment: @Lindydancer thanks for the comment, but in my answer I put the quote that Emacs supports bracket expressions but it doesn't support bracket expressions within a character class, so `[:digit:]` while `[[:digit:]]` is not

Comment: The way I read it, it's the opposite. Emacs support character classes **only** in bracket expressions, so `[[:digit:]]` match a digit whereas `[:digit:]` does not. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special -- the last section under "character alternative" describes this.

Comment: I just noticed that the documentation you referred is not for Emacs, its for a package called "findutils".

Comment: @Lindydancer for your first comment I understand clearly `you would need to use ‘[0-9]’ instead of ‘[[:digit:]]’`. But your second comment called my attention about the Findutils, the weird thing is in its parent [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions) mention about Emacs regex. I'll leave the answer so OP can check another alternative, it might help him to reach the same using the regex I posted too. Thank you man for bring that.

Answer (score 1):

With reverse-sign `[^some-character]` also newlines are matched. In the example the "\n" of second-line is matched, nothing else.

Call this at beginning of buffer:

```
(progn (re-search-forward "^[^[:digit:]]" nil t 1)
       (message "%s" (match-string-no-properties 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp doesn't match the digit at all, it only matches the newline character. The reason it matches it because the newline character isn't a digit.

You can verify this by evaluating the following on the empty line between the digits. It will mode the point to the end of the match, i.e. **before** the digit:

```
(when (looking-at "^[^[:digit:]]") (goto-char (match-end 0)))
```

So what would you like to do instead. In a way, your regexp work for you since it matches empty lines, and they do not beginning with a digit. However, if you would like to exclude empty lines, you can use the following `"^[^[:digit:]\n]"`. This will also exclude lines starting with a newline character, i.e. empty lines.